# COPY TO CSV внутри процедуры в postgresql

Tags: postgresql, хранимые-процедуры

Стоит задача написать процедуру для экспорта данных из таблицы в csv файл, и есть два параметра у процедуры: путь к файлу и разделитель в csv файле.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при попытке создать такую процедуру я получаю ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако если захардкодить путь к файлу, то все хорошо и на плейсхолдер второго параметра не жалуется. Как победить эту проблему?

Comment: Путь к файлу как задаёте? может проблема в отсутствии "\\"? задаете как "c:\report" вместо "c:\\report"? ... или наоборот?

Comment: гляньте сюда: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43999585/pass-parameters-to-stored-function-in-postgres